# SQL date values converted to integers

Tags: sql-server, date, integer, type-conversion

Ok, I can't understand this thing.

A customer of mine has a legacy Windows application (to produce invoices) which stores date values as integers.

The problem is that what is represented like `'01.01.2002'` (value type: date) is indeed stored in SQL Server 2000 as `731217` (column type: integer).

Is it an already known methodology to convert date values into integers (for example - I don't know - in order to make date difference calculations easier?)

By the way, I have to migrate those data into a new application, but for as much I googled about it I can't figure out the algorithm used to apply such conversion.

Can anybody bring some light?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the number of days since Jan 1st 0000 (although that year doesn't really exists).

Anyway, take a date as a reference like Jan 1st 2000 and look what integer you have for that date (something like 730121).

You then take the difference between the integer you have for a particular date and the one for your reference date and you that number of days to your reference date with the DATEADD function.

```
DATEADD(day, *difference (eg 731217 - 730121)*, *reference date in proper SQLServer format*)
```

You can adjust if you're off by a day a two.